# AngularJS - Run setInterval() inside $routeChangeStart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, settimeout

I am using setInterval() to check (every couple of seconds) if a user's token has expired. However, because I have included inside of $routeChangeStart, the interval runs each time the route changes. So for example: if I load the page then click on a different route, then, the interval runs again, for a total of two intervals running. I have set clearInterval() at the beginning because I thought that it would stop any current intervals running. However, this does not stop the interval from running on each route change. Other than running the interval outside of $routeChangeStart, is there a way to stop the interval when a route changes, and then re-initiate it?

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
    clearInterval(interval);

    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        var token = $window.localStorage.getItem('token');
        self.parseJwt = function(token) {
            var base64Url = token.split('.')[1];
            var base64 = base64Url.replace('-', '+').replace('_', '/');
            return JSON.parse($window.atob(base64));
        }
        var expireTime = self.parseJwt(token);
        var timeStamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
        var timeCheck = expireTime.exp - timeStamp;

        if (timeCheck <= 0) {
            console.log('time expired');
            clearInterval(interval);
        } else {
            console.log('time not expired');
        }
    }, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Destroy the interval with `$scope.on('$destroy', function () { $interval.cancel(intervalReturnValue);});`
in the controller where you start the interval

Answer (score 0):

You should use the angular `$interval` instead.  `$interval` is a wrapper around `setInterval` which returns a promise object.  The promise can be cancelled.

something like the following should work:

```
var interval = $interval(function() {
    ...
}, 2000);
```

then, if you need to cancel the interval,

```
$interval.cancel(interval);
```

Note that `$interval` needs to be injected into your service or controller.

Comment: thank you but this produced the same issue of running each time the route changes

Answer (score 0):

in the same scope level catch event `$routeChangeSuccess` but make the definition of the 2 variables `interval`,`count` out of the `$routeChangeStart` it will be like this , 
and if you need to clear it from inside it will be like this #2

```
var interval;
var count = 0;
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart',function(){

  interval = setInterval(function() {
    count++;
   // make what you need here 
   // #2
   if(condition == true){
     clearInterval(interval);
   }
  },2000);
});
 //here if you need after route change  
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess',function(){
   if(count == 1 ){
    count = 0;
    clearInterval(interval)
   }
});
```